# Llamar a un servlet a través de un jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Quería saber si se puede llamar a un `servlet` a través de una página `jsp` sin ser un formulario o tener un botón que llame al `doGet()`;
Yo dispongo de una página que sólo se encarga de listar alumnos, donde quiero que reciba un `Array` de alumnos que provenga del método `doPost` del `Servlet`.

Método doGet()

```
ArrayList<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();    

Alumno al1 = new Alumno();
al1.setNombre("Marcelo");
al1.setApellido("Cuellas");
alumnos.add(al1);

Alumno al2 = new Alumno();
al2.setNombre("Olivia");
al2.setApellido("Hye");
alumnos.add(al2);

request.setAttribute("alumnos", alumnos);    
request.getRequestDispatcher("listar.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Archivo listar.jsp es una lista donde dentro iteraría lo que recibo del doGet(), y creo las row de la tabla.

```
<c:forEach items="${alumnos}" var="alumno">
    <tr>
        <td>${alumno.nombre}</td>
        <td>${alumno.apellido}</td>
        <td>${alumno.DNI}</td>
        <td>${alumno.email}</td>
        <td>${alumno.promedio}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Quería saber si hay alguna forma que esto funcione, sin tener que crear un botón que accione al doGet, o alguna pagina anterior que tenga un hipervínculo al servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un poco tarde pero te respondo, a lo mejor te sirve.

Para llamar a un servlet debes hacer submit a un formulario, no hay otra. En realidad sí que hay - por ajax. Algo así, con javascript:

```
function llamadaAjax(url) {
    _ajaxCall(url, 'POST', function(data) {
        // callback, haz lo que quieras con los datos
    });
}

function _ajaxCall(url, method, callback) {
    var xhttp = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhttp.overrideMimeType) {
            xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!xhttp) {
        alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP request');
        return false;
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callback(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

En realidad hay muchas formas de hacerlo, seguro que los puristas te van a dar un montón de ideas.

En tu servlet escribe los datos directamente en el response, no los metas como atributo al request, y los recibes en la funciona javascript de callback. Eso sí, deben ser serializables.

Aun así te recomiendo que hagas submit al formulario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si recién estuve leyendo acerca de que necesito algo que desencadena la acción para que ejecute el servlet, así que voy a optar por usar input hidden para llamar a las diferentes acciones que quiero realizar.